# Is the expectation of an optimization problem the same as optimizing the expectation of the problem?

Tags: optimization, stochastic-processes

Given a problem $\mathcal{P}$ with with control variable $u$ and uncertainty variable $w$ expressed like:
\begin{equation}
\min_u{f_0(w,u)}\\
s.t.\quad f_i(w,u) \leq 0, \quad 
\end{equation}

In the  Stochastic Programming literature, you can find many ways to treat this general problem like minimizing the $\mathbb{E}f_0$ commonly subject to $\mathbb{P}(f_i<0)>p_i$ i.e. chance constraint, or some other like Value at Risk(VaR), CVaR, or just robust over a set.

As far as I understand, the Montecarlo simulation of this problem could be seen as $\mathbb{E}\mathcal{P}$ and I found a definition that stochastic programming can be expressed as the problem $\mathcal{P'}$.

\begin{equation}
\min_u{\mathbb{E}f_0(w,u)}\\
s.t.\quad \mathbb{E}f_i(w,u) \leq 0, \quad 
\end{equation}
So the question is: is $\mathcal{P'}$ equivalent to $\mathbb{E}\mathcal{P}$ i.e. the same $min$ and the same $argmin$?.

Comment: what is 'the Montecarlo simulation of this problem' exactly?

Comment: I think I understand the question based on the title. Take the unconstrained problem of minimizing $(w^2-u)^2$, the optimal solution is $u=w^2$, and the solutions are different

Comment: You are right LinAlg, thank you very much. By the Montecarlo simulation of $\mathcal{P}$ I mean $\mathbb{E}(min(\mathcal{P}))$ and the $\mathbb{E}(argmin(\mathcal{P}))$. And in your counterexample, it is clear to see that the expected min's are different although the expected argmin's coincide. Thank you very much again.